# What's the best way to create a paging gridview-style partial view in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, webforms, paging, fubumvc

In the current MVC project I'm working on, I need to be able to create something exactly like the GridView from asp.net webforms.  I'm actually using FubuMVC, but I can adapt any Asp.net MVC solution to the Fubu framework.

I want to create something that has the same kind of functionality as the GridView.  To explain further, I mean I want something to list 10-20 items out of a list of 100-200 items, with sorting and paging.

Currently, I could create something like this straight-up in MVC on a case-by-case basis, depending on what I was trying to list.  Implementing sorting and paging as controller actions, or something similar, but it seems like such a common problem that their must be some type of reusable solution.  Only problem is that I can't think what the optimal solution to this problem is.

So, what's the best way to create a gridview-style something in Asp.net MVC?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [jQGrid](http://www.jqgrid.com/).  It does all that and a bit more.

Comment: +1 on this. We use it at work and it works pretty well. It's easy to setup actions in Fubu that produce output models that match the JSON requirements of jqGrid (I know, because that's what we did at Dovetail)